# google invisible recaptcha keeps running without execute

Tags: javascript, invisible-recaptcha

I'm trying to use google invisible recaptcha on my web form (php and codeigniter 3). but somehow whenever I click on the `Submit` button, the google recaptcha keeps generating questions as if ignoring all the other codes before the `execute` command. so none of the `console.log` and `alert` ever appear. what is wrong with my code?

my code looks like this:

HTML

```
<form id="form_signup" method="post" action="/signup">
  <input type="text" name="username"/>
  <div class="g-recaptcha"
    id="form_signup-recaptcha"
    data-size="invisible"
    data-sitekey="<?php echo $mysitekey; ?>"
    data-callback="onSubmitFormSignupUser">
  </div>
  <button type="button" id="formSignup-btnSubmit">
    Submit
  </button>
</form>
```

JS

```
var widgetId = '';

var onLoadRecaptcha = function() {
    widgetId = grecaptcha.render('formSignup-btnSubmit', {
        'sitekey' : $('#form_signup-recaptcha').attr('data-sitekey'),
        'callback' : $('#form_signup-recaptcha').attr('data-callback'),
    });
};

var onSubmitFormSignupUser = function(response) {
    console.log('response', response);

    if ($('[name="username"]').val()) {
        alert('yes');
        grecaptcha.execute(widgetId);

        doSubmitFormToServer('#form_signup');
    }
    else {
        alert('no');
        grecaptcha.reset(widgetId);
    }
}

var doSubmitFormToServer = function(selector) {
    var myData = $(selector).serializeArray();

    console.log('send form data', myData);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you had a typo in the id, at least, here `id="form_signup-recaptcha"` and here: `'sitekey' : $('#formSignup-recaptcha').attr('data-sitekey'),`, other than that, it is not clear, was it invoked at all, or not, as you've not provided the part of including the script, which should contain `?onload=onLoadRecaptcha` parameter.

The code is below, but it won't work here, because of `null` origin. Check Codepen instead: https://codepen.io/extempl/pen/abOvBZv

`sitekey` used is one is for testing purposes only, as described here: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq#id-like-to-run-automated-tests-with-recaptcha-v2-what-should-i-do

```js
var widgetId = "";

var onLoadRecaptcha = function() {
  widgetId = grecaptcha.render("formSignup-btnSubmit", {
    sitekey: $("#form_signup-recaptcha").attr("data-sitekey"),
    callback: $("#form_signup-recaptcha").attr("data-callback")
  });
};

var onSubmitFormSignupUser = function(response) {
  console.log("response", response);

  if ($('[name="username"]').val()) {
    grecaptcha.execute(widgetId);
    doSubmitFormToServer("#form_signup");
  } else {
    $(".status").text("failed");
    grecaptcha.reset(widgetId);
  }
};

var doSubmitFormToServer = function(selector) {
  var myData = $(selector).serializeArray();
  $(".status").text("submitted");

  console.log("send form data", myData);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onLoadRecaptcha"></script>

<body>
  <form id="form_signup" method="post" action="/signup">
    <input type="text" name="username" />
    <div 
      class="g-recaptcha" 
      id="form_signup-recaptcha" 
      data-size="invisible" 
      data-sitekey="6LeIxAcTAAAAAJcZVRqyHh71UMIEGNQ_MXjiZKhI" 
      data-callback="onSubmitFormSignupUser">
    </div>
    <button type="button" id="formSignup-btnSubmit">
    Submit
  </button>
    <span class="status"></span>
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: you're right. but even after I fixed the selector, the captcha keeps appearing before the console.log..

Comment: @dapidmini  in my implementstion there is success console log _after_ execute

Answer (score 0):

it turns out that the solution is so simple.

this code

```
var onLoadRecaptcha = function() {
  widgetId = grecaptcha.render("formSignup-btnSubmit", { // wrong element ID
    sitekey: $("#form_signup-recaptcha").attr("data-sitekey"),
    callback: $("#form_signup-recaptcha").attr("data-callback")
  });
};
```

should be like this

```
var onLoadRecaptcha = function() {
  widgetId = grecaptcha.render("form_signup-recaptcha", { // corrent element ID
    sitekey: $("#form_signup-recaptcha").attr("data-sitekey"),
    callback: $("#form_signup-recaptcha").attr("data-callback")
  });
};
```

because the recaptcha element is like this

```
<div 
  class="g-recaptcha" 
  id="form_signup-recaptcha" 
  data-size="invisible" 
  data-sitekey="6LeIxAcTAAAAAJcZVRqyHh71UMIEGNQ_MXjiZKhI" 
  data-callback="onSubmitFormSignupUser">
</div>
```

so basically the parameters for `grecaptcha.render` should follow the properties in the element that has `g-recaptcha` class. my mistake was that I used the button id, even though the element with `g-recaptcha` class was the div.

I don't remember reading about this particular thing in the documentation. I guess I'm too stupid to realize that before this.. I hope this makes things clear for others with the same problem.